# Batch job does not process all the records from Custom Metadata

Tags: batch, limits

We have a batch job that queries all the records from Custom metadata(CMDT) and processes them in executebatch() one by one and sends emails .

`return IRR_SEL_AutomatedMessagesSelector.newInstance().selectAutomatedMessages();`

There are 1000+ records in CMDT.But we are seeing that batch job does not process all the records.

`ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(processAutomated, 1);`

As you can see from above line, we are processing one batch at a time.
So is there a limit on how many batches can be created in a batch job? Ideally there should be 1069 batches created in the batch job(as there are 1069 records in CMDT) but I have checked the debug log and see that only 100 logs(1 log per batch) are created.
Appreciate some inputs on this.

Code:

```
//querying the records from CMDT

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
return IRR_SEL_AutomatedMessagesSelector.newInstance().selectAutomatedMessages(); 
}
```

```
global override void executeScope( Database.BatchableContext bc, SObject[] sObjScope ) {

for ( SObject message : sObjScope ) {

// do some checks
List<MOD_PassengerInfo> PaxInfo = CON_AutomatedCommunication.getPassengerInfos(
          (String)message.get('Departure_Country__c'),
          (String)message.get('Arrival_Country__c'),
          (String)message.get('Duration__c')
        );
MOD_AutomatedRequest automatedRequest = new MOD_AutomatedRequest();
        
          automatedRequest.passengerInfos = PaxInfo;

//makes the call out
CON_AutomatedCommunication.sendAutomatedCommunication(
          automatedRequest
        );

}
}
```

```
// execute
    SBS_ScheduledBatch processAutomated = new IRR_BCH_SendAutomatedMessage();
    ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(processAutomated, 1);
```

Comment: Even though it's a batch job, you say that you are querying the records one by one - are you doing the querying in a single transaction? 100 SOQL queries in a single transaction is the governor limit. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#transaction_gov_limits_section

Comment: Sorry if that's unclear, I am querying them all in a single transaction in start method and then process them one by one in execute batch.

Comment: The issue might be within the batch job itself, so I suggest editing your question to add the pertinent batch class code.

Comment: Added the code. When I check the debug logs, the operation 'SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler ' is always 100 generated by my batch job? Is there a limit to how many batches you have in any batch job?